# Optional dot in regex

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

Say I want to replace all the matches of `Mr.` and `Mr` with `Mister`.

I am using the following regex: `\bMr(\.)?\b` to match either `Mr.` or just `Mr`. Then, I use the [`re.sub()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) to do the replacement.

What is puzzling me is that it is replacing `Mr.` with `Mister.`. Why is this keeping the dot `.` at the end? It looks like it is not matching the `Mr\.` case but just `Mr`.

```
import re
s="a rMr. Nobody Mr. Nobody is Mr Nobody and Mra Nobody."
re.sub(r"\bMr(\.)?\b","Mister", s)
```

Returns:

```
'a rMr. Nobody Mister. Nobody is Mister Nobody and Mra Nobody.'
```

I also tried with the following, but also without luck:

```
re.sub(r"\b(Mr\.|Mr)\b","Mister", s)
```

My desired output is:

```
'a rMr. Nobody Mister Nobody is Mister Nobody and Mra Nobody.'
                     ^                              ^
                     no dot            this should be kept as it is
```

Comment: You are grouping the optional '.' character.

Comment: You could also use a workaround [`\bMr\b\.?`](https://eval.in/220805)

Comment: @hwnd that is a nice way! I like it, thanks.

Comment: @fedorqui did you want to match `Mr` in `foo:Mr:bar` ?

Comment: @AvinashRaj `:` is not likely to appear in my strings. The only possible case is `Mr-Nobody`, which should also be expanded to `Mister`. So, the idea is that all `Mr` or `Mr.` should be expanded to `Mister` unless an alphanumeric character appears after them.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think you want to capture `'Mr'` followed by *either a `'.'` **or** a word boundary*:

```
r"\bMr(?:\.|\b)"
```

In use:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"\bMr(?:\.|\b)", "Mister", "a rMr. Nobody Mr. Nobody is Mr Nobody and Mra Nobody.")
'a rMr. Nobody Mister Nobody is Mister Nobody and Mra Nobody.'
```

Comment: Nice! What edge cases prevents `?:`? To me, `\bMr(\.|\b)` works fine.

Comment: @fedorqui what's the need for capturing the dot or a word boundary exists after `Mr`?

Comment: @fedorqui and also [this](http://regex101.com/r/hG0qD3/1) answer would also replace `Mr` in `foo:Mr:bar` . Wanna complete and exact match try this [`(?<!\S)Mr\.?(?!\S)`](http://regex101.com/r/hG0qD3/2) regex.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer. It would be helpful (to me and to future readers) to know the reasion of the `?:` block. Accepting it because it really matches my needs. And thanks @AvinashRaj for the nice hints, they could be wrapped in a very good answer.

Comment: @fedorqui `(?:...)` means non-capturing group, there are plenty of existing resources explaining regex syntax

Comment: @fedorqui `(\.|\b)` also captures whatever is right behind Mr so you can, for example, reuse it after you regexed the sentence. `?:` makes it so it doesn't happen. It has barely any impact on performance and readability, but it can help immensely if you are repeating a group an unknown amount of times and then need to capture a group behind that repeated group. making the repeated group non-capturing means that you know in advance what the index of the captured group is and don't have to calculate it first.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs I would say that it has a significant impact on readability, especially if it's pointless in this case.

Comment: Isn't it more simple to write `\bMr\b\.?` ?

Answer (score 7):

```
re.sub(r"\bMr\.|\bMr\b","Mister", s)
```

Try this.You need to remove `\b` after `.`

Output:`a rMr. Nobody Mister Nobody is Mister Nobody and Mra Nobody.'`

The reason why `\bMr(\.)?\b` is not working because between `.` and `space` there is no word boundary.

There are three different positions that qualify as word boundaries:

- Before the first character in the string, if the first character is a word character.
- After the last character in the string, if the last character is a word character.
- Between two characters in the string, where one is a word character and the other is not a word character.

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear enough in my question: `Mra` must be kept as it is, I don't want it to be replaced to `Mistera`. That is, I want either `Mr.` or `Mr` + word boundary.

Comment: OP don't want to match `Mr.` in `Mr.hghggh`

Comment: This is an excellent answer, thank you very much for the very insightful explanation on what I did wrong, how can you do it correctly and why. I am chosing @jonrsharpe 's answer as the accepted because it is more straight forward, but definitely upvoting this.

Answer (score 7):

I think that in the original post the `\b` was the cause of some of the confusion.

From [regex101](http://regex101.com/):

> \b matches, without consuming any characters, immediately between a
>   character matched by \w and a character not matched by \w (in either
>   order).

and

> \w matches any letter, number or underscore.

The OP expected the `\b` to match the boundary between the dot and the space following it. But it didn't, because the dot is not matched by `\w`. Instead the `\b` matched the boundary between the "Mr" text and the dot. That caused the dot to not be captured which was what the OP was asking about. This can be seen here:

[image]

Comment: Interesting! Note, though the a string starting with `Mr` wouldn't be replaced with your current solution. That's the reason of the word boundary `\b`.

Comment: Good point! I was going by the example too literally. I removed the solution and left behind the explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> s="a rMr. Nobody Mr. Nobody is Mr Nobody and Mra Nobody."
>>> re.sub(r'\b(Mr[\.\s]\s*)',r'Mister ',s)
'a rMr. Nobody Mister Nobody is Mister Nobody and Mra Nobody.'
```

Comment: This works but it will replace multiple spaces after "Mr" into one space. See http://regex101.com/r/sC9nG6/4 To avoid this problem you could use `re.sub(r'\b(Mr(\.)?(\s+))',r'Mister\3',s)` instead. See http://regex101.com/r/sC9nG6/5

Answer (score 3):

```
re.sub(r'\bMr[\s\.]', 'Mister ', s)
```

If this was Code Golf would I win?

Comment: @fedorqui - thanks - that, of course, is what I had intended.

Comment: The problem is, this solution converts Mr.␣Nobody to Mister␣␣Nobody. That is, it adds an extra space. See regex101.com/r/dE1yF6/1

Answer (score 0):

@jonsharpe's answer works, but this one is a bit simpler: `\bMr(\.|\b)`

http://regex101.com/r/sC9nG6/2

Comment: `(?:...)` is there to avoid unnecessary capturing.

Comment: But it gives the desired output.

Comment: Of course, it does, but what is the improvement in this answer? The other answer explicitly makes the group non-capturing to slightly reduce the overhead.

Comment: This answer has fewer symbols in it for readers to parse. From the Zen of Python: "Readability counts."