# Splitting a string before "Mr." or "Mrs."

Tags: python, regex, split

I've got a file which contains a string that looks like this:

```
"TextMr. XxxxxMrs. YyyyyMrs. ZzzzzTextWordLady ZzzzzMr. Xxxxx"
```

Now, I want to split it with Python so that it looks like that:

```
['Text', 'Mr. Xxxxx', 'Mrs. Yyyyy', 'Mrs. Zzzzz', 'Text', 'Word', 'Lady Zzzzz', 'Mr. Xxxxx']
```

At the moment I am using the following:

```
test2 = re.sub( r"([A-Z])", r" \1", data).split()
```

which gives me:

```
['Text', 'Mr.', 'Xxxxx', 'Mrs.', 'Yyyyy', 'Mrs.', 'Zzzzz', 'Text', 'Word', 'Lady', 'Zzzzz', 'Mr.', 'Xxxxx']
```

I know that it's probably very simple and have also read all the threads I could find about regex and titles but nobody seemed to have the same problem. I would be very happy if somebody could point me in the right direction and tell me what  am doing wrong (once, I spent an hour staring at a code snippet that wasn't working only to discover that I simply forgot a `*`) since I would love to understand regex.

Comment: The pattern would be `Mrs?\.`

Comment: Related: [Optional dot in regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26907640/optional-dot-in-regex) also with Mr / Mrs dot issue.

Comment: how do `ZzzzzText` get split?

Comment: You can use `(?:(?:Mrs?\.|Lady) )?[A-Z][a-z]*` regex to find all necessary matches - https://regex101.com/r/kE4hF5/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you create a list with all the possible titles that can go by a name first:

```
>>> titles = "Mr\. Mrs\. Lady Sir".split()
['Mr\\.', 'Mrs\\.', 'Lady', 'Sir']
```

You can then use those to create regex for any of those titles, followed by a space.

```
>>> title_opt = "(?:(?:" + "|".join(titles) + ") )?"
'(?:(?:Mr\\.|Mrs\\.|Lady|Sir) )?'
```

And then use those titles followed by a word to find all the names and words.

```
>>> re.findall(title_opt + "[A-Z][a-z]+", text)
['Text', 'Mr. Xxxxx', 'Mrs. Yyyyy', 'Mrs. Zzzzz', 'Text', 'Word', 'Lady Zzzzz', 'Mr. Xxxxx']
```

---

Or, building upon your own approach, once you have the list of names, words and titles, you could use an iterator to join titles to the `next` word from the iterator.

```
>>> names = ['Text', 'Mr.', 'Xxxxx', 'Mrs.', 'Yyyyy', 'Mrs.', 'Zzzzz', 'Text', 'Word', 'Lady', 'Zzzzz', 'Mr.', 'Xxxxx']
>>> titles = set("Mr. Mrs. Lady Sir".split())
>>> iterator = iter(names)
>>> [s if s not in titles else s + " " + next(iterator) for s in iterator]
['Text', 'Mr. Xxxxx', 'Mrs. Yyyyy', 'Mrs. Zzzzz', 'Text', 'Word', 'Lady Zzzzz', 'Mr. Xxxxx']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(.+?)(?=Mr\.|Mrs\.|$|(?<! )[A-Z])
```

Try this.See demo.Grab the capture.

https://regex101.com/r/sJ9gM7/59#python

```
import re
p = re.compile(r'(.+?)(?=Mr\.|Mrs\.|$|(?<! )[A-Z])', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = "TextMr. XxxxxMrs. YyyyyMrs. ZzzzzTextWordLady ZzzzzMr. Xxxxx"

re.findall(p, test_str)
```